# Notion of distance in a Conformal Field Theory

Tags: conformal-field-theory, field-theory

I'm confused about the how the notion of distance is used in [Conformal Field Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_field_theory). Let's take for example the [Operator Product Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_product_expansion) (OPE).

In a conformal field theory, due to the scale invariance only angles - and not distances - matter. But in the very definition of the OPEs one speaks about *two operators evaluated at nearby points*. How can one make sense of this apparent contradiction?

Comment: Where's the contradiction? The OPEs are exactly valid up to the next insertion point of other operators (i.e. the convergence radius of the Laurent expansions is precisely the distance to the next insertion).

Comment: _"In a conformal field theory, due to the scale invariance only angles - and not distances - matter."_ That's not quite true! All that scale invariance guarantees you is that things transform nicely as you zoom in and zoom out. You don't see something weird happening as you zoom past a special scale. So one can _pick a scale unit_ for calculation, and then ensure that all physical answers are non-dimensionalized by the same unit, so that they respect scale invariance.

Comment: To add to my comment above, if distances really did not matter, then you are wrecking serious havoc with the notion of locality/causality! (You most definitely don't do that in a conformal quantum field theory)

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix a coordinate system $X$, then for any two points A and B the distance $d(A,B)$ between the two can be defined and calculated from the metric in that particular coordinate system, allowing you to define limits of this type:

For a sequence of points $P_n$ and a point $Q$, $P_n\rightarrow Q$ if and only if $d(P_n,Q)\rightarrow0$.

It's true that if we now change coordinate systems all the distances will be modified and because this is a CFT the distances are not really physical so there is no preferred coordinates system. Nevertheless, the definition of limit above is coordinate independent and if the limit exists in one system it will exist (and be the appropriately transformed point) at any.

In the definition of OPEs limits are used to calculate the behavior as two operators are inserted at two points approaching each other. It is then shown that it also makes sense to calculate the same quantity for two operators that are not approaching each other as long as "there are no other operators around". In this sense, nearby points mean that if we draw the circle centered at one point with a radius that extends to the other point, this circle will not have any other operators inserted in it.

Comment: you don't need the notion of a metric in a conformal field theory, the OPE is a more primitive concept. all you need is coordinate charts, holomorphic transition functions (if the underlying manifold is a complex manifold), and cocycle relations in order to ensure that all coordinate charts glue together in a globally well-defined manner.